# Average of Groupby into a dataframe timedelta64[ns]

Tags: python, dataframe

df1

```
|Project |Days
|A       |20 days
|B       |10 days
|A       |10 days
|C       |5 days
|C       |7 days
|B       |8 days
```

R = df1['Days'].groupby(df1['Project'])

R

```
|20 days
|10 days
|Name: Days, dtype: timedelta64[ns],('A', 30   15 days)
|10 days
|8 days
|Name: Days, dtype: timedelta64[ns],('B', 18   9 days)
|5 days
|7 days
|Name: Days, dtype: timedelta64[ns],('C', 12   6 days)
```

df2

```
|Project  |Date     |**New Date**
|A        |1/10/16  |1/25/16 
|A        |1/8/16   |1/23/16
|C        |1/2/16   |1/8/16
|B        |1/9/16   |1/18/16
```

What I'm trying to do is create `df2['New Date']` by using the average of days by Project in df1 and add that average to `df2['Date']`.  Any thoughts?

Also wanted to add.  The 'Days' column is generated from taking the difference between two dates loaded in from an excel spreadsheet.

****EDIT****

df1.head().to_dict('list')

```
 {'Project': ['210001', '210001', '210001', '210001', '210001'], 'Days':
 [Timedelta('8 days 00:00:00'), Timedelta('8 days 00:00:00'), Timedelta('12 days
 00:00:00'), Timedelta('12 days 00:00:00'), Timedelta('14 days 00:00:00')]}
```

df1.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1161 entries, 0 to 1278
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Project    1161 non-null object
Days      1161 non-null timedelta64[ns]
dtypes: object(1), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 22.7+ KB
None
```

EDIT #2  INT
This is the error I'm getting on:  OverflowError: int too big to convert

```
df2['New Date'] = df2['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df2['Days'], unit='D')

Days
20.569231
15.795455
20.569231
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Days': ['20 days', '10 days', '10 days', '5 days', '7 days', '8 days'],
     'Project': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B']}) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': ['1/10/16', '1/8/16', '1/2/16', '1/9/16'],
     'Project': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B']})

df1['Days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Days']) 
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

result = df1.groupby('Project')['Days'].agg(['sum', 'count'])
result['Days'] = result['sum']/result['count']
df2 = pd.merge(df2, result[['Days']], left_on='Project', right_index=True)
df2['New Date'] = df2['Date'] + df2['Days']
print(df2)
```

yields

```
        Date Project  Days   New Date
0 2016-01-10       A  15.0 2016-01-25
1 2016-01-08       A  15.0 2016-01-23
2 2016-01-02       C   6.0 2016-01-08
3 2016-01-09       B   9.0 2016-01-18
```

---

Compute the `groupby/mean`:

```
result = df1.groupby('Project')['Days'].agg(['sum', 'count'])
result['Days'] = result['sum']/result['count']
#             sum  count    Days
# Project                       
# A       30 days      2 15 days
# B       18 days      2  9 days
# C       12 days      2  6 days
```

and merge this `result` with `df2` (joining on `Project`):

```
df2 = pd.merge(df2, result[['Days']], left_on='Project', right_index=True)
#         Date Project    Days
# 0 2016-01-10       A 15 days
# 1 2016-01-08       A 15 days
# 2 2016-01-02       C  6 days
# 3 2016-01-09       B  9 days
```

Then, add the `Days` to the `Date`:

```
df2['New Date'] = df2['Date'] + df2['Days']
```

Comment: df1['Days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Days']) / pd.Timedelta(days=1)

I get a KeyError: 'Days' when I use this line.

Comment: Are you getting that error when you run my code from the top (including my definition of `df1`)?

Comment: I am not.  I made an simplified example dataset using df1 and df2.  The code you provided works perfectly but I cannot seem to get it to work with my current project.

Comment: Please post `df1.head().to_dict('list')` and `df1.info()`.

Comment: Added in Edits with the above.  Thanks!

Comment: Everything looks good from the point of view of dtypes. I don't see any reason why my code should raise a KeyError when applied to your actual data -- provided, of course, that you've changed `Days` to `DaysToPay` -- e.g. `df1['DaysToPay'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['DaysToPay']) / pd.Timedelta(days=1)`.

Comment: Does `df1['Days']` raise the KeyError?

Comment: I got it to work.  I keyed df1['days] instead of df['Days'] =/
The issue I have now is an overflow error: int too big to convert.
The Days field has a lot of integers after the . that may be causing that is my guess.  Is there a way to limit the amount of 'float' of the particular integers?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by "The Days field has a lot of integers after the ."?

Comment: Edit #2 made above.

Comment: What is `df1['Days'].max()`? You might be experiencing [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14080). This happens if the Timedeltas are extremely big. If that is the cause of the problem, then it's not clear to me how you managed to get the Timedeltas into `df1['Days']` without seeing the overflow error first. In other words, you should have seen that overflow error even before running my code. Nevertheless, 
I made a change to the code to avoid the conversion of Timedeltas to floats and back. This *might* avoid the problem.

Comment: I was able to fix it by using     result['Days'] = result['Days'].astype(np.int64)

Comment: Thanks for the help!